# Не запускается Jupyter Notebook в Pycharm Pro, система Linux Mint

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

не запускается Jupyter в PyCharm Pro, с такой ошибкой:

'''Jupyter server process exited with code 1 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/nikolay/Python/Projects/Jupyter_Notebook/venv/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in   from notebook.app import main File "/home/nikolay/Python/Projects/Jupyter_Notebook/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/app.py", line 9, in   from jupyter_server.base.handlers import JupyterHandler File "/home/nikolay/Python/Projects/Jupyter_Notebook/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 23, in   from jupyter_events import EventLogger File "/home/nikolay/Python/Projects/Jupyter_Notebook/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_events/**init**.py", line 3, in   from .logger import EVENTS_METADATA_VERSION, EventLogger File "/home/nikolay/Python/Projects/Jupyter_Notebook/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_events/logger.py", line 18, in   from .schema import SchemaType File "/home/nikolay/Python/Projects/Jupyter_Notebook/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_events/schema.py", line 18, in   from .validators import draft7_format_checker, validate_schema File "/home/nikolay/Python/Projects/Jupyter_Notebook/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_events/validators.py", line 41, in   JUPYTER_EVENTS_SCHEMA_VALIDATOR = Draft7Validator( # type: ignore TypeError: create. .Validator.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'registry'

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка возникает из-за того, что установленная вами версия jsonschema слишком старая (jupyter_events требует >=4.18.0, но если вы, например, установили поэзию в той же виртуальной среде, это приведет к понижению версии пакета.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык